# aws console not opening

Tags: amazon-web-services, console

AWS console not opening in all three browsers I have namely edge, firefix and chrome. seems to be logging in but after that web page is blanket.
at the end of the page I see lines of Feedback, Engilsh(US), Terms etc
the problem happening from yesterday.
anybody else having same problems?
region is US-West-2
tried clearing browser cache and then logging into console but no luck.
any idea what could be issue and how to troubleshoot the issue in my win10 desktop
does aws has any desktop client for the console function?

regards
Babu

Comment: Are you connecting from work? Maybe your corporate firewall is blocking something. Use the Chrome developer tools and see if you can find any network errors or console output that's helpful. You can use the awscli or ElasticWolf (client-side tools) in the meantime, or use the awscli to launch a Windows instance and then use that to access the AWS console from a browser.

Comment: no problems here, checked safari and chrome

Comment: thanks. tried using chrome developer tools and find the following network error. https://d363lb6z73zzbk.cloudfront.net/01a4541549b699de9c056f3b4ad7b722367a415a/rds/rds.nocache.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. not sure what this means?

Comment: just tried opening EC2 console and is opening but RDS console not opening ( I have only RDS instance). does this mean issue is at aws end? or is there a possibility of issue at my end? also tried tarcert to cloudefront.net and is completing within 110ms

Answer (score 3):

Try using a VPN. I was also facing the same issue but after connecting to the VPN it worked just fine. Also, keep on trying without a VPN on a regular basis because the probably is usually with the ISP and may be fixed at anytime.